# Is there an anticommutator relation for orbital angular momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, lie-algebra, anticommutator

So I know that there are commutator relations for $L$ such as $[L_x,L_y] = i\hbar L_z$, but is there a relation for the anticommutator? For example, $L_xL_y + L_yL_x$?

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking anticommutators are not defined in a Lie algebra. The axioms only define the commutators. Clearly since we are used to represent the commutator as
$$
[A,B] = AB - BA\,,
$$
this might seem silly because, you know, why can't we just flip the sign? But the formal definition doesn't need $A$ and $B$ to be matrices and doesn't say what $AB$ is. It just defines an object that satisfies antisymmetry, bilinearity and the Jacoby identity.

Nevertheless it's possible to extend a Lie algebra to a [Universal enveloping algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra) which contains formal polynomials of the generators ($A\otimes B \otimes \cdots $ ) and in such an algebra the commutator is represented as one would expect ($A \otimes B - B \otimes A$). Needless to say, if you use matrices all this comes for free and $\otimes$ is just the row by column product.

In this universal enveloping algebra then the anticommutator would be obviously defined as
$$
\{A,B\} \equiv A \otimes B + B \otimes A\,.
$$
All this detour just to say that it doesn't come from the algebra but it *depends on the representation* (indeed one of the elements of the universal enveloping algebra in $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is the Casimir $$L^2 \equiv L_x\otimes L_x + L_y\otimes L_y + L_z\otimes L_z$$ which is even used to label representations).
In the fundamental representation of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ the generators are Pauli matrices and we know
$$
\{L_i,L_j\} = \frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij}\mathbb{1}\,.
$$
More generally we might expect other tensors to appear in the right hand side. So the final answer would be
$$
\{L_i,L_j\} = a(R)\delta_{ij}\mathbb{1} + M(R)_{ij}\,,
$$
where $R$ denotes the representation considered, $a(R)$ is just a number and $M(R)$ satisfies
$$
\mathrm{Tr}[M(R)_{ij}] = \sum_i M(R)_{ii} = \mathrm{Tr}[M(R)_{ij}L_k] = M_{ij}-M_{ji} = 0\,.
$$
I took part of this from the answers to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221851/196314), you might want to check those! One thing that I should add if you are considering reading that thread is that in there they consider $\mathfrak{su}(N)$ for arbitrary $N$, the neat fact about $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is that the so-called cubic casimir $d_{ijk} = \mathrm{Tr}[\{L_i,L_j\}L_k]$ actually vanishes, meaning that the extra piece is only the one orthogonal to the generators (that is the $M(R)$ piece)

Comment: But then this begs the question: why should angular momentum operators be related to a Lie algebraic structure?

Comment: Because rotations in 3 dimensions form a group and this group is a Lie group. Lie algebras emerge naturally from Lie groups (hence the name).

Comment: You should include (and maybe expand a bit) this in your answer as it’s quite essential to understanding why should Lie algebras be relevant to this question.

Comment: Worth emphasizing: if something depends on the representation, physically this means it depends on the total angular momentum, e.g., the anticommutators will be different for spin-1/2 vs. spin-1 particles.

Answer (score 2):

Well, given any anticommutator,
$$ \{A, B\} = AB + BA = AB - BA + 2BA = [A, B] + 2BA.$$

Thus any anticommutator relation can be written in terms of a commutator relation, with an extra term dangling off the back. But that extra term doesn't represent anything of value, so I don't see how it would be useful.

Personally, I've never come across anticommutators before, so I may be very wrong.

Comment: what does “won’t contribute” mean in this context?  contribute to what?

Comment: It means that they don't represent anything of value, or that they don't add some extra meaning. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The anticommutator does not appear much in elementary quantum mechanics: for instance, whereas *commuting* operators have common eigenvectors, anticommuting operators do not.

Anticommutators do occur quite naturally in the demonstration of Robertson's uncertainly relations.  In fact, if one wishes to go from a lower bound to a strict equality to find states that satisfy
$$
\Delta A\Delta B = \frac{1}{2}\vert\langle [\hat A,\hat B]\rangle\vert
\tag{1}
$$
rather than the more common inequality, one needs to set the average value of the *anticommutator* to $0$, i.e. $\langle \Delta A\Delta B+\Delta B\Delta A\rangle=0$
with $\Delta A=\hat A-\langle A\rangle$ etc.  It is interesting to note here that, even if the right hand side of the uncertainty relation depends on the commutator,  ones needs results on the anticommutator to get the "=" sign.

States that satisty the strict equality $\Delta A\Delta B = \frac{1}{2}\vert\langle [\hat A,\hat B]\rangle\vert$ are called *intelligent* and were studied in

1. Aragone, C., et al. "Intelligent spin states." Journal of Physics A: Mathematical, Nuclear and General 7.15 (1974): L149,
2. Aragone, C., E. Chalbaud, and S. Salamo. "On intelligent spin states." Journal of Mathematical Physics 17.11 (1976): 1963-1971.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be open-access copies of these papers.

As alluded to in another answer, there is a deep relation between Lie algebras and commutators, but *not* anticommutators.  In particular, the tools of representation theory can be used for various purposes when the observables close under commutation on a Lie algebra.  The case of angular momentum follows because the operators $\hat L_x, \hat L_y, \hat L_z$ are infinitesimal generators of rotations, and the group of rotations is a Lie group.

Note that, in the special case of Pauli matrices, there is a neat relation for anticommutators: $\{\sigma_a,\sigma_b\}=2\delta_{ab}$ but this is quite specialized and such a clean relation does not hold for larger angular momentum matrices.