# Anticommutator of spin-1 matrices

Tags: angular-momentum, representation-theory, lie-algebra, clifford-algebra, anticommutator

We know that in the spin-1/2 representation the anticommutation relation of the Pauli matrices is $\{\sigma_{a},\sigma_{b}\}=2\delta_{ab}I$. Does a similar relation hold for the spin-1 representation?

Comment: Related question: [Is there an anticommutator relation for orbital angular momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/454715/)

Answer (score 2):

Of course not, [in general](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221851/the-anticommutator-of-sun-generators),  as the anticommutator is in the universal enveloping algebra: it is not even in the Lie algebra augmented by the identity, as evident in the specific example below.

For the spin 1 representation of the algebra, $J^a_{~~bc}=-i\epsilon_{abc}$, consisting of hermitean, imaginary, antisymmetric 3×3 matrices, i.e. the  adjoint representation, it is straightforward to [compute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Index_and_symbol_values) all anticommutators explicitly,
$$
\{J^a,J^b  \}_{mk}= -\epsilon_{amn}  \epsilon_{bnk} -\epsilon_{bmn}\epsilon_{ank}= 2\delta_{ab}\delta_{mk} -(\delta_{am}\delta_{bk}+\delta_{bm}\delta_{ak}).
$$

You then see the r.h.s. are symmetric real matrices.

- For $a\neq b$, they are traceless off-diagonal ones;
- For $a=b$, they are diagonal, traceful ones, but with a 0 in the *ab* entry.