# Anti-commutator of angular momentum operators for arbitrary spin

Tags: angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, anticommutator

I know the commutator of angular momentum operators are
$$
[J_i,J_j]=\mathrm i\hbar \varepsilon_{ijk}J_k.
$$
For spin-1/2 particles, $J_i=\frac\hbar2\sigma_i$ where $\sigma_i$ are Pauli matrices, and I can compute $\{J_i,J_j\}$ from the algebra of $\sigma_i$'s,
$$
[\sigma_i,\sigma_j]= 2\mathrm i\varepsilon_{ijk}\sigma_{k},
\quad
\{\sigma_i,\sigma_j\}=2\delta_{ij}1 \!\!1_2.
$$
When it comes to higher dimensons, these relations are broken.

I want to know what are the relations in higher dimensions.

---

[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/228026/289541) shows the case for a fundamental representation of $SU(N)$,
$$
\{t^{A},t^{B}\} = \frac{2N}{d}\delta^{AB}\cdot 1_{d} + d_{ABC}t^{C},\tag{1}
$$
where
$$
\mathrm{Tr}[t^{A}t^{B}] = N\delta_{AB}\quad
d_{ABC} = \frac{1}{N}\mathrm{Tr}[\{t^{A},t^{B}\}t^{C}].\tag{2}
$$
If I substitude Eq.(1) into Eq.(2), I get
$$
d_{ABC}=\frac1N \frac{2N}{d}\frac1N\mathrm{Tr}[t^At^B] \cdot  \mathrm{Tr}[t^C]
+\frac1N d_{ABD}\mathrm{Tr}[t^Dt^C]
$$
where $\mathrm{Tr}[t^C]=0$. Above equation dosen't tell me how to compute $d_{ABC}$,
since $\mathrm {Tr}[t^D t^C]=\delta_{DC}\mathrm{Tr}[1_d]=N\delta_{DC}$.

Comment: What I'm dealing with is actually $SU(2)$, not for arbitrary $N$.

Comment: The *d* coefficient of *su(2)* always vanishes. Your right hand side is ***not in the Lie algebra***, but, instead, in the universal enveloping algebra, addressed in answers to the linked questions. There is no good formal theory for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the adjoint (3d irrep) of *su(2)*, it is straightforward to [compute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Index_and_symbol_values) all anticommutators explicitly,
$$
\{J^a,J^b  \}_{mk}= -\epsilon_{amn}  \epsilon_{bnk} -\epsilon_{bmn}\epsilon_{ank}= 2\delta_{ab}\delta_{mk} -(\delta_{am}\delta_{bk}+\delta_{bm}\delta_{ak}),
$$
in  variant normalization, $(J^a)_{mn}=i\epsilon_{amn}$,  which is the least of your problems.

You see by inspection that, for $a\neq b$, the right-hand side is a symmetric traceless matrix, so *not* a linear combination of the three generators! Your equation (1) *fails*.

Keep reading other answers in that question. *su(2)* irreps are real/pseudoreal, so anomaly coefficients vanish, as your QFT text must have  emphasized.

But I am unaware of a generic shortcut expression for M.

Experiment with [higher spin representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins), all explicit. Can the r.h.s. of $\{S_x,S_z\}$, traceless,  be represented by a linear combination of the three generators? *(No! You may readily compute it for arbitrary spin *s*, given item 4 of this link, and confirm it is symmetric  with vanishing diagonal elements, but is **not** $\propto S_x$, the only generator with these properties!)*

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/454756/66086).