# Inner product on group theoretic coherent states and anti-commutator of Lie algebra generators

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, group-representations, coherent-states

This question is related to group theoretic coherent states (Gilmore, Perelomov etc.). I consider a semi-simple Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and a unitary representation $U(g)$ acting on some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Given a Lie algebra element $A$, I will refer to its induced representation as $\hat
{A}$.

Given a state $|\psi_0\rangle$, I can define the sub Lie algebra
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{h}=\left\{A\in\mathfrak{g}\,\big|\,\hat{A}|\psi_0\rangle=0\right\}\,.
\end{align}
Due to the fact that $\mathfrak{g}$ is semi-simple, its Killing form $K$ is non-degenerate, so I can define the unique orthogonal complement
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{h}_{\perp}=\left\{A\in\mathfrak{g}\,\big|\,K(A,B)=0\forall B\in\mathfrak{h}\right\}\,.
\end{align}
Clearly, I have $\hat{A}|\psi_0\rangle=\hat{A}_{\perp}|\psi_0\rangle$, where $A_{\perp}$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\mathfrak{h}_{\perp}$ of $A$.

I would like to pull back the Hilbert space inner product onto the Lie algebra, i.e., my parametrization $U(g)|\psi_0\rangle$ describes a sub manifold in Hilbert space. At the identity, i.e., at $|\psi_0\rangle$ the tangent space is given by
\begin{align}
\mathcal{T}_{|\psi_0\rangle}\mathcal{M}=\{\hat{A}|\psi_0\rangle\,|\,A\in\mathfrak{g}\}=\{\hat{A}|\psi_0\rangle\,|\,A\in\mathfrak{h}_{\perp}\}\,.
\end{align}
In concrete examples, I found the relationship
\begin{align}
G(A,B)=2\mathrm{Re}\langle\psi_0|\hat{A}^\dagger\hat{B}|\psi_0\rangle=-K(A_{\perp},B_{\perp})\,,
\end{align}
i.e., the pull back of the Hilbert space inner product (real part of it) is given by the negative Killing form evaluated on the orthogonal complement of the stabilizer Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$ associated to $|\psi_0\rangle$.

My intuition is that this should be true in general (under certain conditions, such as $|\psi_0\rangle$ being highest weight or similar. To prove this or find the relevant conditions, I would need to compute the expression
\begin{align}
G(A,B)=2\mathrm{Re}\langle\psi_0|\hat{A}^\dagger\hat{B}|\psi_0\rangle=-\langle\psi_0|\hat{A}_{\perp}\hat{B}_{\perp}+\hat{B}_{\perp}\hat{A}_{\perp}|\psi_0\rangle\,,
\end{align}
where I used that the representations of generators must be anti-Hermitian.

That's the point where I am stuck. Any suggestions how to proceed or references that discuss this issue?

Comment: I would have posted this question in the mathematics section, not the physics one.

Comment: @DanielC: Well, when searching I found this question (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221851/the-anticommutator-of-sun-generators/362009#362009) which is slightly related and similar in style. The respective question in the math section didn't receive many answers, so I thought that physics section is more promising...