# Why do Gell-Mann matrices have this normalization?

Tags: group-theory, conventions, lie-algebra, trace

This might be a stupid question, but why is the normalization of the Gell-Mann matrices (basis of the $\mathrm{su}(3)$ Lie algebra) chosen to be
$$\mathrm{trace}(\lambda_i\lambda_j)=2\delta_{ij}$$
instead of just $\delta_{ij}$ without the factor $2$? In most of linear-algebra, basis vectors are normalized to $1$ (or not normalized at all). Why not in the context of Lie Algebras? Is there a way of looking at this which makes the factor $2$ seem natural?

On a related note, some physics texts change the normalization by defining "the generators of the $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ group" as $T_i=\frac{1}{2}\lambda_i$. But these just fulfil $\mathrm{trace}(T_iT_j)=\frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij}$ which seems just as unnatural to me. (And the difference between these two normalization conventions just cost me an hour of chasing a missing factor $4$ in a long calculation. Which is why I'm asking this question xD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

History. The Gell-Mann matrices are an extension/generalization of the Pauli spin matrices for *su(2)*, and $\lambda_{1,2,3}$ identify with these, so obey the same trace relation.

You also understand why the Pauli matrices are further normalized this way by an extra 1/2, so as to then obey the canonically normalized *su(2)* algebra with structure constant *ε*, thereby avoiding half-angle exponentials.

Comment: well, Pauli matrices have the same "problem" of $\mathrm{tr}\sigma_i\sigma_j=2\delta_{ij}$ (also $[\sigma_i\sigma_j]=2i\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k$). But changing their normalization would destroy the rather nice property $\sigma_i^2=1$ (which implies Eigenvalues$=\pm 1$ and Determinant$=-1$). These properties even kinda carry over to Gell-Mann, whose eigenvalues are $1,-1,0$ (except for $\lambda_8$). Thanks, Cosmas.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos: Actually, it would be nice if you could expand your answer a bit, because I wonder why only in gauge theory the normalisation Lie-algebra generators is done, but not in representation theory. Why is this so? Why does it matter in gauge theory? Secondly, the trace of 2 generators looks like a killing form $B(x,y) = tr(ad_X, ad_Y)$. Curiously for a compact group like $SU(2)$ I would expect a negative normalisation $tr(t_i, t_j)=-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij}$, and in some books it is indeed like this, but why not here ?

Comment: Sorry, normalization is an endless subject... In gauge theory you care about group identities and Casimirs, anomaly coefficients, etc.. and normalizations matter, e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221851/the-anticommutator-of-sun-generators/362009#362009). In rep theory they don't care... it's beneath them. Note in physics we like hermitian generators with an i on the r.h.side of the Lie algebra, whereas mathematicians naturally go for real structure constants...

Comment: By contrast, for the rotation group, where the generators are [real, antisymmetric matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_constants), the structure constants are real without an i... It's all conventions of convenience.