# More than one 15 dimensional irrep of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$

Tags: group-theory, notation, representation-theory

The irreps of (complexified) $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ are labelled by highest weight Dynkin labels $(a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1})$, and are often referred to simply by their dimension, e.g. $\mathbf{3}$ to label $(1, 0)$ of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$. Now consider the $(2, 1)$ and $(4, 0)$ irreps of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$: both have dimension 15, but they are not dual (the dual of $(2, 1)$ is $(1, 2)$). Is there a standard way in the physicists notation to distinguish such irreps? If not, then is there ever any (physical) need to do so?

Comment: $\boldsymbol{15}$ and $\boldsymbol{15'}$.

Comment: The habit of HEP people to denote irreps by their dimension is terrible.  The Dynkin notation removes a significant level of confusion and is much preferred.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I think it's fine in PSE as the question relates to the need (in physics rather than math) to distinguish the irreps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

? Of course physicists use the standard Dynkin indices, as you confirm by using your [Slansky 1981](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.1581&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Table 23, p 92.

Even though your two irreps have the same
$$
d(p,q)= \tfrac{1}{2} (p+1)(q+1)(p+q+2)  ~~~~\leadsto ~~~ 15,
$$
Their quadratic Casimirs entering in the [β function of QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function_(physics)#SU(N)_Non-Abelian_gauge_theory) are different, eigenvalues
$$
(p^2+q^2+3p+3q+pq)/3  ~~~~\leadsto ~~~  28/3  \leftrightarrow  16/3,
$$
respectively; and the cubic Casimir eigenvalues, rescaled to the respective [anomaly coefficients](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/362009/66086), are
$$
(p-q)(3+p+2q)(3+q+2p)/18  ~~~~\leadsto ~~~  154/9   \leftrightarrow 28/9 ,
$$
so they'd contribute differently to anomalies.

Comment: Interesting! It is certainly common to ignore Dynkin indices and just to write e.g. $\mathbf{15}$ though. Is there any way to distinguish the two irreps using this notation, or are we simply meant to assume that it refers to the 15-dimensional irrep with the lowest weight (i.e. $(2, 1)$ rather than $(4, 0)$)?

Comment: No, the dimensionality is not a unique label of a representation. I've no idea what  might be meant  to be assumed. Perhaps that there is some  **15** in the Clebsch reduction that will not feature in the discussion again, and the number of states are a correction check in the counting of states...

Comment: If I recall the convention is that **15** is the totally symmetric one, (4,0), probably because it arises more naturally from multiplying together smaller irreps.

Comment: @LukePritchet Actually, Slansky uses **15** for (2,1) and **15**' for (4,0), but who cares? Given ambiguity, any reasonable author would specify exactly what she/he means through Dynkin labels.

Answer (score 2):

The irreps are really different, as illustrated by branching rules to subgroup and other relevant quantum numbers.

For instance the $(4,0)$ contains angular momenta $L=4,2,0$ but the $(2,1)$ contains $L=3,2,1$.  The branch to $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ irreps is also different.

The irrep $(4,0)$ does not have weight multiplicities but the irrep $(2,1)$ has three weights occurring twice.  Thus the *physical* contents are certainly different.